# Call form submission programatically upon icon click in Javascript/VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I want my single page application (Vue 3 / Quasar 2) to invoke a logout request to my Spring-based backend.

My first approach was using an axios request when the logout icon has been clicked:

```js
axios.post('http://localhost:8500/logout');
```

However, this does not work because the AJAX requests run into a CORS issue when following redirects. It seems as if Spring requires this to be a browser-initiated form POST to work correctly.

So I changed my SPA code to this:

```xml
<q-form
    action="http://localhost:8500/logout"
    method="post"
    ref="logoutForm"
>
    <q-icon
    name="o_logout"
    size="sm"
    @click="logout"
    />
</q-form>
```

But I'm struggling with how to call the form's `submit` event in the `logout()` method when the icon was clicked.

---

#### Update 1

Here is the code snippet:

```js
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ToolbarElements',
  setup() {
    const logoutForm = ref(null);

    function logout() {
      ref('logoutForm').submit();
    }

    return {logout, logoutForm };
  },
});
</script>
```

But this gives me the follow error:

`vue__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.ref(...).submit is not a function`

---

#### Update 2

I found out that I used the `ref` in a wrong manner, so I corrected the code to be:

```js
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'ToolbarElements',
  setup() {
    const logoutForm = ref(null);

    function logout() {
      logoutForm.value.submit();
    }

    return {logout, logoutForm };
  },
});
</script>
```

This results in a new error message:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e is undefined`

Comment: You don't want to call its submit _event_, but its submit _method_. And what is the actual struggle? Get a reference to the form element (add an ID to it maybe, if you have trouble selecting it), and then call the method. Can you show us what you tried?

Comment: @CBroe I updated my original question with the relevant code.

Comment: `ref()` is probably returning some complex object, not a reference to the DOM node itself - same as `$()` would in jQuery. You need to get the reference to the DOM node, because that is the object providing the `submit` method.

Comment: Does it have to be an actual form? You can send the data using `multipart/form-data` as the content type, would that work?

Comment: Well, I assume it needs to be an actual form as the browser needs to follow the redirects as a result of the logout url.